# Laravel Lumen, Swagger: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined error

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, lumen

I installed SwaggerLume and it works well on the path of '`/docs`', but it doesn't with the path of '`/api/documentation`', giving me an error like below.

```
- Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined
    at window.onload (documentation:75:20)
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js?v=9c0d82f1bb63b730b3470d714fa36c1a:1:1)
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at swagger-ui-bundle.js?v=9c0d82f1bb63b730b3470d714fa36c1a:1:1)
```

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNvJ8.png)

I have the `swagger-ui-assets` in my public folder but it's giving me an empty screen when I try to route `/api/documentation`.